# Is splitting one hurdle model in two GLM/GAM models a valid approach?

Tags: r, count-data, zero-inflation

I came across several publications dealing with overdispersed zero-inflated count data that "simply" modelled presence absence in one model and then postive counts in a second model. This led to two models with two different outcomes. The authors stated they were using "hurdle models".

In my opinion hurdle models do not work like that but "integrate" the results of both models in one step in one final output, is this right?

Is the other approach now "wrong" ??

Comment: I've not seen results from hurdle models 'integrated'; what does that look like?  Do you have examples of papers that do that?  (It might be helpful to link to the papers you found that have two separate models as well.)

Comment: soorry for answering so late. In the paper "Identifying essential summer habitat of the endangered beluga whale Delphinapterus leucas in Cook Inlet, Alaska" by Goetz et al. Endangered Species Res. 16: 135-147 (you can find it on google), they build two single models with glmmPQL() and did not combine the models "statistically"; only the predicted results were multiplied at the end(!!!). Is this okay? For sure not I would say

Comment: Hi @Jens, sorry I don't have time to look at it further right now with the semester starting next week.  Hopefully someone else will; that's the great thing about this site!

Comment: sure, no problem. I´ll hang on here ;)

Comment: I think that ZIPs have only recently been fully integrated into the world of generalized linear mixed models.  So, if Goetz et al wanted random effects in both the binomial and the poisson models they might have been unable to fit an integrated model.  The package glmmADMB (http://glmmadmb.r-forge.r-project.org/glmmADMB.html) can fit mixed model ZIPS.  Zuur et al 2012 get at this I think via WinBUGS (http://www.highstat.com/book4.htm)

Comment: Yes, glmmadmb, gamlss, pscl, vgam, there are some packages that allow for ZIP/ZANB combined with random effects. I also bought the Zuur - Book4. I will post my WinBUGS experience later

Comment: I would think not as well.  Regression using a truncated sample will yield biased coefficients.  In tobit the marginal effects can be decomposed into the probability of the outcoming occurring weighted by the predicted score and the predicted score weighted by the probability of outcome occurring, there was a paper by McDonald and Mofffitt (1980) about this.  But the approach you describe does not follow from this; 2-part models include a correction (i.e. the hazard rate or "inverse mills ratio") to address the bias resulting from truncation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just randomly came across this question. Sorry it's so late. It is fine to model the two parts of a hurdle model separately. This paper addresses hurdle and zero-inflated models
https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2017/RJ-2017-066/index.html

Using data from the glmmTMB package here's an example. You could fit the data with either a zero-inflated model (`zinb` below, where zeros can be from either the negative binomial or the zero-inflation) or with a hurdle model (`hnb` below). Then we can see that `hnb` is statistically equivalent to the combination of a binomial model for the zeros and a zero-truncated model for the positive counts.

```
> zinb = glmmTMB(count~spp * mined + (1|site), zi=~spp * mined, data=Salamanders, family=nbinom2)
> 
> hnb = glmmTMB(count~spp * mined + (1|site), zi=~spp * mined, data=Salamanders, family=truncated_nbinom2)
> 
> zeros = glmmTMB(count<.5 ~spp * mined, data=Salamanders, family=binomial)
> 
> pos = glmmTMB(count ~spp * mined + (1|site), data=subset(Salamanders, count>0), family= truncated_nbinom2)
> 
> logLik(pos)
'log Lik.' -491.5107 (df=16)
> 
> logLik(zeros)
'log Lik.' -315.2394 (df=14)
> logLik(pos)+logLik(zeros)
'log Lik.' -806.7501 (df=16)
> 
> logLik(hnb)
'log Lik.' -806.7501 (df=30)
```

You can also see the coefficients if you try it.

Comment: Many thanks! It is never too late for a good answer.